# Taking an infinite number of logarithms

Tags: limits, logarithms

Let $n$ and $k$ be two integer parameters ($n\geq k$, if that matters). Define the following function:

$\text{LOG }x=\max(\log{x},1)$

What is the limit of the following sequence as a function of $n$ and $k$?

> $a_1 = \text{LOG }n$
>
> $a_2 = \text{LOG }k \cdot \text{LOG }\text{LOG }n$
>
> $a_3 = \text{LOG }k \cdot \text{LOG }\text{LOG }k \cdot \text{LOG }\text{LOG }\text{LOG } n$
>
> $a_4 = \text{LOG }k \cdot \text{LOG }\text{LOG } k \cdot \text{LOG }\text{LOG }\text{LOG }k \cdot \text{LOG }\text{LOG }\text{LOG }\text{LOG }n$
>
> ...

I looked at [Iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm) in Wikipedia, this looks similar but not the same.

A limit in terms of big-Oh notation is fine (e.g. $O(f(n,k)$).

Comment: I think the sequence is ill-defined. For sufficiently large $N$, $\log\log\cdots\log k$ is going to be $<0$ and then, $a_{N+1}$ would not be a real number anymore. Of course, if your sequence can be complex then it is okay.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay Thanks! I corrected the question.

Comment: Doesn't your edit imply that the limit will be equal to 1?

Comment: @AGoogler You are right, my previous edit didn't make sense. I hope the current edit does.

Comment: I think the new limit will also be 1 , but I'm sure I'm wrong.

Comment: Is $n$ fixed? ..

Comment: @AGoogler The new limit cannot be 1 because the sequence is monotonically increasing.

Comment: @user3491648 I am looking for the limit as a function of $n$ and $k$

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi Your limit is finite. I don't think it can be expressed using elementary functions. If $L(N,k)$ is your limit as a function of $N$ and $k$ then $\log(k) \leq L(N,k) \leq \log(k)^{\log^*k}$. In practical terms, it's a constant multiple of $\log(k)$. Also it's completely independent of $N$

Comment: @user3491648 you probably mean: a constant power of $\log(k)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$LOG LOG \dotso LOG(N) \rightarrow 1$ so we can ignore that completely. You can generate the proof by looking at a cobweb plot and noticing that the limit must be in the intersection of $y = x$ and $y = \text{LOG }x$ which is at $x = 1, y = 1$.

As far as $\text{LOG } k \text{ LOG } \text{LOG } k \text{ LOG } \text{ LOG } \text{ LOG } k \dotso$ after finitely many of those the sequence will stay the same. The $n$ at which this happens is the iterated log of $k$. A not very tight big-O is $O(\log(k)^{log^*k})$

Comment: Is it correct to say that, for all practical purposes, the bound is $O(log^5(k))$?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi LOG LOG $k$ is *much much* slower growing than LOG $k$, to the point that it's practically constant. that's the best answer i can make given how much effort i'm willing to put into this question

Answer (score 1):

Let us agree upon the notation $f^{(n)}(x)=(f\circ f\circ\cdots f)(x)$. Then According to your current definition, note that $\exists N$ such that $LOG^{(N)}n=\log^{(N)}n,\ LOG^{(N+1)}=1$.  Similarly, you can find a $K$ such that $LOG^{(K)}k=\log^{(K)}k,\ LOG^{(K+1)}=1$. So, for $m\ge \max(K+1,N+1),\ a_m=\prod_{i=1}^{K}log^{(i)}k$ which is a constant, i.e your sequence converges to a constant number.

I think the problem becomes more interesting if you define $LOG x=1+\log x$, just like the definition of the iterated logarithm function.

**Edit:** Note that $f(k)=\log^{(K)}k$ is the number such that $\log(f(k))<0$ for the first time. So we need to find this $K$. Let us define the sequence $b_n=\log^{(n)}k,\ n\ge 0$ with $b_0=k$. Then, by the previous analysis, your original sequence is going to converge to $a$ where $\log a=\sum_{n=1}^K \log b_n$ where $K$ is such that $b_{K+1}<0,\ b_i>0,\ 1\le i\le K$. One can easily see that $\{b_n\}$ is a positive monotonic decreasing sequence; so $b_n\ge 1\ \forall 0\le n\le K$. Now, using LMVT we can write $$b_{n+1}-b_{n}=\frac{b_n-b_{n-1}}{c_n},\ \forall 1\le n\le K-1\\ \implies \frac{b_n}{b_{n-1}}<\frac{b_{n-1}}{b_{n-2}},\ 2\le n\le K$$ since $c_n\in (b_n,b_{n+1})$. Now, it can be easily shown that $$\frac{b_1}{b_0}=\frac{\log k}{k}<\frac{1}{e}\approx 0.3679=:\alpha$$  Thus, $b_n<\alpha^{n}k,\ 1\le n\le K\implies K<\log\log k\implies \log a<K\log k-\frac{K(K+1)}{2}<\log k\cdot \log\log k-1\implies a=O((\log k)^{\log k})$

Comment: I agree that the sequence eventually converges to a finite number, but this number is a function of $n$ and $k$, and this is the function I am looking for...

Comment: Ok, I see, let me think about it.

Comment: I think you did not define $c_n$.

Comment: $c_n$ is the constant that you get when applying LMVT, It basically is $f'(\theta x)$. I mentioned  in the answer that $c_n\in (b_n,b_{n+1})$.

Comment: Thanks! Your bound seems correct, but, I had to accept the other answer because the bound there is tighter.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi, its okay. I just wanted to see what bound could be found analytically. BTW I found this another found which is tighter.